# Invoke an IdentityUser in ViewComponant?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Services_Website.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Services_Website.ViewComponents
{
    public class CurrentUser : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public CurrentUser(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUser Invoke()
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn((ClaimsPrincipal)User))
            {
                var userId = _userManager.GetUserId((ClaimsPrincipal)User);
                var UserFinded = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;

                return UserFinded;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is my code I want to return in Invoke method an object of ApplicationUser or IdentityUser but when write the the code like this I getting this error.
 how can I do that

---

the error

> InvalidOperationException: View components only support returning String, IHtmlContent or IViewComponentResult.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ApplicationUser inside a ViewModel

**ViewModel**

```
public class CurrentUserVM
{
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set;}
}
```

**ViewComponent Code**

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn((ClaimsPrincipal)User))
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId((ClaimsPrincipal)User);
        user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
    }
    return new CurrentUserVM()
    {
        ApplicationUser = user;
    }
}
```

**ViewComponent View**

```
@model CurrentUserVM

// your view code
```